# How can we move the endpoints from one CDN profile to another?

Tags: azure-cdn

I want to move some endpoints from one CDN profile to another CDN profile since we hit our maximum number of endpoints per CDN profile. Is there any way that I can move the required endpoints from one CDN to another using powershell or is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Moving CDN end points across profiles involves downtime as the only option here is to delete the present connection and reconnect those endpoints to a new profile. We cannot eliminate downtime in this process.